# WP login pages redirect to homepage (cannot login)

Tags: login

The wp-admin and wp-login.php pages in my site redirect to the landing page, so I cannot log in.

The theme is one I made from scratch, for the first time, so I'm pretty sure that is where the mistake is.

The website is https://uberpasscodes.com/

Any solutions to get in?

Thanks

Comment: Deactivate all your plugins, switch to a default theme and enable `WP_DEBUG`. Maybe a `login_redirect` hook is acting from somewhere.

Comment: Have you transferred your website from some where else ? (Sorry i know it should be comment, but i don't have much reputation.)

Comment: @DaniyalAhit yes it was developed locally and then migrated to production server

Comment: @DaniyalAhmed Then please gain some reputation by answering one or two questions with valuable content. Thanks.